# How to disable RDP bitmap caching system wide

Tags: windows, security, cache, rdp

I'm trying to find a way to completely disable bitmap caching for RDP clients (In Windows 10 the setting is called "Persistent bitmap caching") on a Windows system, either through GPO or registry.

I know I can do this for individual .rdp files, but this is not what I'm looking for, since a user could just create a new .rdp file with other settings.

I want to do this because of security reasons, not because of technical issues ;-)

Does anyone know if this is possible and how?